# Type Safe Coding

Tags: asp.net, type-safety

When i started developing web applications i stored the authentication details of the user in two session variables

```
 Session["UserName"]="username";
 Session["Password"]="paswword-123";
```

But someone proposed me an idea to create a class which holds the UserName and Password properties and on succesful authentication i have been asked to create an instance of the class and set the UserName and Password properties and store that instance in the session.

I have been told that the session object is TypeSafe. Can someone explain what is typesafe coding and the advantage of storing the object in the session.

Comment: Who told you this? In what context exactly - the above? Do you have a link to a page that says that?

Comment: when i was in college one of my professors told me.. is something wrong or insensible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, the classic approach of storing values directly in `Session["something"]` has two drawbacks:

- **Magic strings**: If you mistype `something`, your code compiles fine but you get either a runtime error or, worse, an unnoticed bug in your code.
- **Casting**: After reading `Session["something"]`, you need to cast it to the type you need. (This is what is meant by *"not type-safe"*.)

Using a strongly-typed object that is stored in the Session eliminated the second problem. Well, actually, your custom object still needs to be cast, but it's only one cast instead of two (or ten) casts, which reduces the likelyhood of something going wrong. Again, a wrong cast is something which is only detected at run-time.

Another approach is to encapsulate the access to Session variables in static properties:

```
public class MySession {
    public static string UserName {
        get { return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"]; }
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Of course, both approaches can be combined, allowing you to group related properties (UserName and Password) in a common object.

Answer (score 3):

Having a User class with 2 fields can be good for many reasons, as for type safety, if you ever type Session["Pasword"] somewhere you will get an error that wont be so easy to find, you will have to check for both parameter names everywhere. You need them to be correct, and its a great source of errors. Once you store User object instead of 2 unconnected strings you will have be able to use type safe code like User.Password  instead of trying to access password by string indexer in Session. Also if your user ever gets more fields , which is very common you will simply add them to User class, not start creating new parameters & names and store them in Session heap.

As for typesafe coding I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety should help, or any other type of article on topic which is very popular I think.

Also I dont think you should store password in session, depends on your program logic but usually password should only be used to compute its md5 hash and never be used afterwards.

Comment: I'm sure someone this curious must have already checked out the "popular articles" including wikipedia, no?

Comment: How can you be sure in that? anyway I can copy paste what typesefety is from there, Im just not sure what exactly in type safety is unclear to OP, and I dont think I can paste whole article here. Anyway I am trying to help not anything else. To me if someone doesn't understand why Session["xxx"] is not type safe reading whole article cant be bad. (cause it kinda violates the very definition of type safety)

Answer (score 0):

Well you're friend is half right, but I don't believe Session is inherently type safe. The Session collection stores instances of Object. So you can store an instance of any type (a string, an int, or a custom login class) because they all derive from object. However, when you retrieve that object, you don't know what type it is, and need to carefully cast it, with exception handling, before you use it.
eg this works fine:

```
Session["UserName"] = "Freddy";
string theUserName = (string)Session["UserName"];
```

However you could try to do the following, which will cause errors.

```
Session["UserName"] new StrangeDataClass(); //Uh Oh, that's not a string.
string theUserName = (string)Session["UserName"]; //unexpected behaviour based on StrangeDataClass.ToString() implementation.
```

To work around this, you'd have to do the following:

```
string theUserName = Session["UserName"] as string;
if (string != null)
    //The cast worked...
else
    //The cast failed, (or the string stored in session was null)
```

Having a custom login object slightly solves this problem, because you'd only have one object to worry about, and one cast to make. You could also extend the login object easily with extra information, and still not have to do any more casts.